# Java LWJGL - Function is not supported error when trying to render GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, render, lwjgl, illegalstateexception

I am trying to render simple GUI elements to my screen over my 3D game. When I run my program,I get an IllegalStateException saying the Function is not supported. It throws up in the GUI class on the drawRect method:

```
package renderEngine;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class GUI {
public float getRedFromHex(int color) {
    return (float)(color >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255F;
}
public float getGreenFromHex(int color) {
    return (float)(color >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255F;
}
public float getBlueFromHex(int color) {
    return (float)(color & 0xFF) / 255F;
}
public float getAlphaFromHex(int color) {
    return (float)(color >> 24 & 0xFF) / 255F;
}

public void drawRect(float x, float y, float width, float height, int color) {
    float r = this.getRedFromHex(color);
    float g = this.getGreenFromHex(color);
    float b = this.getBlueFromHex(color);
    float a = this.getAlphaFromHex(color);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GL11.glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + height);
    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
}
```

I am calling the method in my render class:

```
private GUI gui = new GUI();

public void render(Light sun, Camera camera) {
    prepare();
    shader.start();
    shader.loadSkyColour(RED,GREEN,BLUE);
    shader.loadLight(sun);
    shader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
    renderer.render(entities);
    shader.stop();
    terrainShader.start();
    terrainShader.loadLight(sun);
    terrainShader.loadViewMatrix(camera);
    terrainShader.loadSkyColour(RED,GREEN,BLUE);
    terrainRenderer.render(terrains);
    terrainShader.stop();
    gui.drawRect(100, 100, 300, 300, 0x00000000);
    terrains.clear();
    entities.clear();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace :P

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor4f(GL11.java:893)
at renderEngine.GUI.drawRect(GUI.java:28)
at renderEngine.MasterRenderer.render(MasterRenderer.java:85)
at engineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:147)
```

Comment: Sorry was late last night, check the EDIT :)

Comment: I assume that your GL version is 3.2+ with core profile, right?

Comment: I believe so yes @SriHarshaChilakapati

Comment: Were either of you going to help me? I added in the stack trace @VinceEmigh

Comment: @KyleJensen Did you check to make sure your GL version is up to date? Believing isn't enough

Comment: @VinceEmigh My GL version is 4.4

Comment: You don't have access to glVertex etc functions when in core profile.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Okay, like ive said, Im new to gl so I have no idea what that means, could you ellaborate a little bit? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.0 Opengl introduced a deprecation model, the functions like glVertex, glColor, glTexCoord, etc., are deprecated.

These deprecated functions are removed in the core profile, they no longer exist, and hence you are greeted with that exception.

What you have to do is instead read up on modern way of opengl, VBOs and VAOs.